# ToDouble always throws an exception when i want to convert a negative number in string format to Double

Tags: c#, string, double

when i run the following code it always throws an exception

```
string a = "-12.12";
double b = Convert.ToDouble(a);

An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
```

what is the problem with the code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suspect you're running in a locale which uses `,` as the decimal separator... or which uses a different symbol for negation. You can pass in a `CultureInfo` to specify how to parse - I usually use `double.Parse` instead of `Convert.ToDouble`:

```
double x = double.Parse(a, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

That will be absolutely fine. If it still doesn't work, that suggests your *actual* string isn't quite "-12.12". For example, if the "-" is actually an en-dash or something like that, it won't parse properly.

Comment: ok i think the problem occurs because i Set the Regional format in my phone device to Persian

Comment: @SoheilGhahremani: Right - so it's exactly as I described. But passing in `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` should still fix it.

Comment: Could you explain why using double.Parse(a, CultureInfo) is better (or how it's different from) Convert.ToDouble(a, NumberStyles)? Would passing AllowDecimalPoint not work with the specific Regional format because it would still expect a `,` instead of `.` for decimals?

Comment: @DanielHoffmann-Mitscherling: Well for one thing, it accepts a `CultureInfo` (via `IFormatProvider`) rather than using the system-default culture - and that's precisely what's required here. (`NumberStyles` is about what kind of number you're parsing, not the cultural aspect.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Cool! Thanks. I'll keep this in mind for future use.